# Force re-render the react component in the jquery single page application or in static html site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, single-page-application

I have created one spa using JQuery. SPA is done via writing a custom router where we add visible classname to a page div to make that page visible and we remove the same classname from all the other pages using jquery like this,

```
$(".main-content .page").removeClass("visible");
const page = $(`#${pageId}`);
page.addClass("visible");
```

Now I am migrating this site to use react components here and there through out the website. I have one component on one of the page that shows product data based on the id in the URL but the problem is that it doesn't rerender even if I change the URL. It is not able to detect the change as state or props are not changing.

is there a way to force rerender this component from my other JS code?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was pretty straight forward but it is not mentioned anywhere.

The official guide says to use this below code at the end of the file so that when our js file will be loaded by the browser and run then it will render our react code but the thing is we can call this method from anywhere to force rerender our component/ replace our component with the new instance.

To force rerender it, calling below method that adds the react code to the div worked.

```
ReactDOM.render(<ProductDetails />, document.getElementById("product-details"));
```

Using this we can even pass the new props also if we want to.